# What is Recurrent Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I recently came across the word of "Recurrent Reinforcement Learning". I understand what "Recurrent Neural Network" is and what "Reinforcement Learning" is, but couldn't find much information about what a "Recurrent Reinforcement Learning" is.

Can someone explain to me what is a "Recurrent Reinforcement learning" and what is the difference between "Recurrent Reinforcement learning" and normal "Reinforcement learning" like Q-Learning algorithm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What is a "recurrent reinforcement learning"?

Recurrent reinforcement learning (**RRL**) was first introduced for training neural network trading systems in 1996. "Recurrent" means that previous output is fed into the model as a part of input. It was soon extended to trading in a FX market.

The **RRL** technique has been found to be a successful machine learning technique for building financial trading systems.

> What is the difference between "recurrent reinforcement learning" and normal "reinforcement learning" (like Q-Learning algorithm)?

The **RRL** approach differs clearly from *dynamic programming* and *reinforcement algorithms* such as **TD-learning** and **Q-learning**, which  attempt to estimate a *value function* for the control problem.

The **RRL** framework allows to create the simple and elegant problem representation, avoids *Bellman's curse of dimensionality* and offers compelling advantages in efficiency:

**RRL** produces real valued actions (portfolio weights) naturally without resorting to the discretization method in the **Q-learning**.

**RRL** has more stable performance compared to the **Q-learning** when exposed to noisy datasets. **Q-learning** algorithm is more sensitive to the value function selection (perhaps) due to the recursive property of dynamic optimization, while **RRL** algorithm is more flexible in choosing objective function and saving computational time.

With **RRL**, trading systems can be optimized by maximizing performance functions, $U(  )$, such as "profit" (return after transaction costs), "wealth", utility functions of wealth or risk-adjusted performance ratios like the "sharpe ratio".

[Here](http://github.com/ceshine/RRL_Matlab) you will find a Matlab implementation of the RRL algorithm.

---

#### References

[Reinforcement Learning for Trading](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/1551-reinforcement-learning-for-trading.pdf)

[Reinforcement Learning for Trading Systems and Portfolios](http://aaaipress.org/Papers/KDD/1998/KDD98-049.pdf)

[FX trading via recurrent reinforcement learning](http://www.trade2win.com/boards/attachments/metatrader/77870d1267907789-build-neural-network-indicator-mt4-using-neuroshell-gold-2003-fx-trading-via-recurrent-reinforcement-learning.pdf)

[Stock Trading with Recurrent Reinforcement Learning (RRL)](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2006/Molina-StockTradingWithRecurrentReinforcementLearning.pdf)

[Algorithm Trading using Q-Learning and Recurrent Reinforcement Learning](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2009/LvDuZhai.pdf)

[EXPLORING ALGORITHMS FOR AUTOMATED FX TRADING – CONSTRUCTING A HYBRID MODEL](http://salserver.org.aalto.fi/vanhat_sivut/Opinnot/Mat-2.4177/projektit2008b/loppuraportti_1_nordea.pdf)

Comment: @AntonDanilov I'm not sure if you're aware of this. The guy who came up with this idea (your first ref., J Moody) has been running a fund using this algo -- and his performance has been far from spectacular.

Comment: So, good to know but how it does changemy answer

Answer (score 2):

The distinction of (Deep) Recurrent RL, is that the function mapping the agents observations to its output action is a Recurrent Neural Network.

A Recurrent Neural Network is a type of neural network that processes each observation sequentially, in the same way for each time step.

Original paper: [Deep Recurrent Q-Learning for Partially Observable MDPs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06527.pdf)